# Phone Field Validation - WooCommerce Checkout Input not highlighted

Tags: woocommerce

In WooCommerce checkout, the `phone` field has a basic validation provided by WooCommerce. When alphabets are entered, an error message is shown but the input field is not shown in red border. Is there any filters or options to make input phone field to behave as other validation required fields ?
I have searched for this and couldn't find any option.